# Video won't play on iPhone 5.0 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, video

Im new to xCode programming, ive got this code from an ebook tutorial playing mp4 xCode.

function triggered from a button

```
(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoSample" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath]; 
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view]; 
moviePlayerController.fullscreen=YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
}
```

called from play movie function

```
(void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification{
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification
                                  object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self
                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                               object:moviePlayerController];
[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Ive got no error and warning after i build it. it just output a blank screen after i click the button that triggers the playMovie function. Im confuse ive google it and still got no idea on how to solve the proble.

Im using xCode 4.2 iOS SDK 5.0

Comment: iOS 5 is still under NDA, and you are not allowed to talk about it outside of the special Apple iOS 5 developer forums

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController (but not MPMoviePlayerControllerView) is not working for me in the simulator and in 4.3, but the device all was OK

Comment: @rckoenes...ohh sorry, my fault. Rest assured this will not happen again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....replace "example" with the name of your file and "m4v" with the type of file e.g. "mp4" (not .mp4 and dont put the .mp4 bit in the name of the file)

```
-(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender;
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"m4v"];


MPMoviePlayerViewController* tmpMoviePlayViewController=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

if (tmpMoviePlayViewController) {

    tmpMoviePlayViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentModalViewController:tmpMoviePlayViewController animated:YES];

    tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                        selector:@selector(myMovieViewFinishedCallback:)

                                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

                                        object:tmpMoviePlayViewController];

    [tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer play];
}
```

}

```
-(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)theNotification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[theNotification object];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayer];

[moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
```

}

Comment: remember to include the -(void) and -(ibaction) bit, dunno why that hasn't gone in properly.

Comment: Typo: in `myMovieFinishedCallback:`, `MPMoviePlayerController` should be `MPMoviePlayerViewController`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for the answer. Here's what you can try - declare the *MPMoviePlayerController* in your header(.h) file (i.e. make it a member variable).

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
```

and add this to your .m file

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
```

If it still does not work then try to declare it as a @property.