# I am trying to add a video to my iOS application but only the audio plays but no video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

i have looked everywhere for answers and have tried all the possible ways, maybe theres something simple i am missing (I'm new to programming) also i have a lot of other stuff going on in the same storyboard board file i have 3 buttons to do other things i wanted the app to load and then the video to play straight away and then go to the main menu which is on the same storyboard.

heres my code:

viewcontroller.m file:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self play];
}

- (void) play
{
    NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"goatmovie1"        withExtension:@"mov"];

m_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[m_player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[[m_player view] setFrame:[self.view frame]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

[m_player play];

[self.view addSubview:[m_player view]];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)_notification
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:nil];

[m_player.view removeFromSuperview];
[m_player stop];
m_player = nil;
}
```

here is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface StartViewController : UIViewController
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* m_player;
}

- (void) play;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ey

you can try the next link : [Video won't play on iPhone 5.0 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443018/video-wont-play-on-iphone-5-0-simulator), there are a couple of more links but this should work.

If it doesnt, take a look into the encoding and look over the apple documentation the the supported formats : http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3775